# Not able to access DOM element textArea from content script

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Error displayed in console :TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null. console log displays contentScript running.

contentScript.js :

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('getText',function(data) {
    var editor = document.getElementById('editText');
    console.log('contentScript running');       
        editor.focus();
        editor.select();
        editor.value=data.getText;  

});
```

webpage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <textarea id="editText" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error means that at the time the content script is executed there is no such element. It can happen if your content script is executed at `document_start` or the site dynamically builds the page after it was loaded in which case you need to check for the element periodically using setInterval or MutationObserver.

Comment: I used setInterval and the error keeps cropping in the specified interval.

Comment: Well, it's hard to guess without a reproducible example.

Comment: Can you provide minimal code with the error you are facing so we can reproduce?

Comment: Check this github gist: https://gist.github.com/shahidw2/b91bd535071ad51540b6c744b1322916

Comment: I got it . the webpage was from google.scripts so it had an iframe and security exception